# How to convert tag names and values from XML into HTML using Perl

Tags: html, xml, perl

Is there any way to convert a simple XML document into HTML using Perl that would give me a table of tag names and tag values?

The XML file `output.xml` is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<doc>
    <GI-eSTB-MIB-NPH>
        <eSTBGeneralErrorCode.0>INTEGER: 0</eSTBGeneralErrorCode.0>
        <eSTBGeneralConnectedState.0>INTEGER: true(1)</eSTBGeneralConnectedState.0>
        <eSTBGeneralPlatformID.0>INTEGER: 2076</eSTBGeneralPlatformID.0>
        <eSTBGeneralFamilyID.0>INTEGER: 25</eSTBGeneralFamilyID.0>
        <eSTBGeneralModelID.0>INTEGER: 60436</eSTBGeneralModelID.0>
        <eSTBMoCAMACAddress.0>STRING: 0:0:0:0:0:0</eSTBMoCAMACAddress.0>
        <eSTBMoCANumberOfNodes.0>INTEGER: 0</eSTBMoCANumberOfNodes.0>
    </GI-eSTB-MIB-NPH>
</doc>
```

I am trying to create HTML which looks like this

```
1. eSTBGeneralPlatformID.0 - INTEGER: 2076
2. eSTBGeneralFamilyID.0 - INTEGER: 25
3.
```

I was trying to use code from the web but I am really having a hard time understanding how to generate the required format for HTML tags.

What I was trying was this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Parser;
use XML::LibXML;

#Add TagNumberConversion.pl here

my $parser = XML::Parser->new();
$parser->setHandlers(
    Start => \&start,
    End   => \&end,
    Char  => \&char,
    Proc  => \&proc,
);

my $header = &getXHTMLHeader();
print $header;

$parser->parsefile( '20150630104826.xml' );

my $currentTag = "";

sub start() {

    my ( $parser, $name, %attr ) = @_;
    $currentTag = $name;

    if ( $currentTag eq 'doc' ) {
        print "<head><title>"
            . "Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4"
            . "</title></head>";
        print "<body><h2>" . "Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4" . "</h2>";
        print '<table summary="'
            . "Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4"
            . '"><tr><th>Tag Name</th><th>Tag Value</th></tr>';
    }
    elsif ( $currentTag eq 'GI-eSTB-MIB-NPH' ) {
        print "<tr>";
    }
    elsif ( $currentTag =~ /^eSTB/ ) {
        print "<tr>";
    }
    else {
        print "<td>";
    }
}

sub end() {

    my ( $parser, $name, %attr ) = @_;
    $currentTag = $name;

    if ( $currentTag eq 'doc' ) {
        print "</table></body></html>";
    }
    elsif ( $currentTag eq 'GI-eSTB-MIB-NPH' ) {
        print "</tr>";
    }
    elsif ( $currentTag =~ /^eSTB/ ) {
        print "</tr>";
    }
    else {
        print "</td>";
    }
}

sub char() {
    my ( $parser, $data ) = @_;

    print $data;
}

sub proc() {
    my ( $parser, $target, $data ) = @_;

    if ( lc( $target ) eq 'perl' ) {
        $data = eval( $data );
        print $data;
    }
}

sub getXHTMLHeader() {

    my $header = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">';

    return $header;
}
```

This is code in progress, but I realize that this will be overkill for my requirement.

So I am trying to figure out if there is any quick way to do it using Perl.

Please give me some pointers if there is indeed any quick way.

Comment: You shouldn't use an ampersand `&` when you are calling Perl subroutines -- just `my $header = getXHTMLHeader()` is correct. And you shouldn't use prototypes when you are defining subroutines -- those `()` after the subroutine names make sure that no parameters are ever passed, which isn't what you want at all. Just `sub start { ... }` is correct. And you should reserve capital letters for global identifiers such as package names -- local identifiers should consist of lower-case letters, decimal digits and underscores

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed the actual HTML that you wanted as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is to just use a regular expression.  However it comes with the risk of missing some data and getting burned by edge cases.  But since you asked for it...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

open my $fh, 'filename.xml'
    or die "unable to open filename.xml : $!";
my $count = 1;
print "<head><title>'Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4'</title></head>\n";
print "<body><h2>'Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4'</h2>\n";
print "<table summary='Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4'><tr><th>Tag Name</th><th>Tag Value</th></tr>\n";
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    next unless $line =~ m|<eSTB|;
    # Store into into $tag and $value
    # the result of matching whitespace, followed by '<'
    # followed by anything (store into $tag)
    # followed by '>'
    # followed by anything (store into $value)
    # followed by '<'
    my ($tag, $value) = $line =~ m|\s+<(.+?)>(.+?)<|;
    print "<tr><td>" . $count++ . ". $tag</td><td>$value</td></tr>\n";
}
print "</table></body></html>\n";
```

Produces the following:

```
<head><title>'Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4'</title></head>
<body><h2>'Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4'</h2>
<table summary='Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4'><tr><th>Tag Name</th><th>Tag Value</th></tr>
<tr><td>1. eSTBGeneralErrorCode.0</td><td>INTEGER: 0</td></tr>
<tr><td>2. eSTBGeneralConnectedState.0</td><td>INTEGER: true(1)</td></tr>
<tr><td>3. eSTBGeneralPlatformID.0</td><td>INTEGER: 2076</td></tr>
<tr><td>4. eSTBGeneralFamilyID.0</td><td>INTEGER: 25</td></tr>
<tr><td>5. eSTBGeneralModelID.0</td><td>INTEGER: 60436</td></tr>
<tr><td>6. eSTBMoCAMACAddress.0</td><td>STRING: 0:0:0:0:0:0</td></tr>
<tr><td>7. eSTBMoCANumberOfNodes.0</td><td>INTEGER: 0</td></tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot xxfelixxx. I used your quick and dirty way and it gets the job done perfectly. I am trying to understand the following line though, which I think is doing pattern matching and something more, like getting the specific part of $line into $tag and $value strings: 
my ($tag, $value) = $line =~ m|\s+<(.+?)>(.+)<|;

Comment: 1. store into variables $tag and $value
2. the result of the pattern match of $line
3. matching spaces followed by a '<' followed by anything
4. capture the 'anything', it goes into $tag
5. matching '>' followed by anything
6. capture the 'anything' it goes into $value
7. followed by '<'

Comment: Hmm... parsing XML with a regex. That *never* goes wrong :-/

Comment: Dave, I tried to install Template module so I could use LibXML instead of using regex, but found that CPAN is not installed (or at least not working now) on the Linux box that I am using. But I'll get CPAN working and will use LibXML for parsing as it'll be a more reliable way and good learning for me as well.

Comment: The absence of the Tempalte Toolkit won't stop you from using XML::LibXML for parsing the XML. You'll just need to use a different approach for creating your output.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think you're using the wrong tool for this. I always find [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML) far easier to use than XML::Parser. You load XML::LibXML, but you never make use of it.

Secondly, I think you'll find your live is easier if you think of this as two stages - one to extract the data and one to output the new data.

Here's the first stage, which stores the data you need in an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use XML::LibXML;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = shift || die "Must give XML file\n";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($file);

my @tags;

# Find the nodes using an XPath expression
foreach ($doc->findnodes('//GI-eSTB-MIB-NPH/*')) {
  push @tags, { name => $_->nodeName, content => $_->textContent };
}

# Just here to show the intermediate data structure
say Dumper \@tags;
```

You then need to use `@tags` to generate your output. For over fifteen years we've know that it's a terrible idea to include hard-coded HTML in amongst your Perl code, so I'd highly recommend looking at a templating system like the [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML).

I created a `xml.tt` file like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4</title>
</head>
<body><h2>Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4</h2>
<table summary='Output of snmpwalk for cpeIP4'>
<tr>
<th>Tag Name</th><th>Tag Value</th><
/tr>
[% FOREACH tag IN tags -%]
<tr><td>[% loop.count %]. [% tag.name %]</td><td>[% tag.content %]</td></tr>
[% END -%]
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And then the second half of my program looks like this:

```
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new;
$tt->process('xml.tt', { tags => \@tags });
```

I hope you agree that all looks a lot simpler than your approach.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I agree that the solution you provided is too neat and simple than what I was trying. I think I don't have supporting module for "Template" though. I am getting error as: Can't locate Template.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Call_to_snmpwalk_V_8.pl line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Call_to_snmpwalk_V_8.pl line 14.
I am trying to find how I can correct this error. I have already included use 5.010 and I am on perl v5.10.1

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the Template module installed. You just need to install it by whatever means you use to install CPAN modules.